# How to compare cells one by one between two Excel sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA code and I'm having some issues.

Here's the context, I have an Excel spreadsheet with two sheets, "Sheet1" and "Sheet2"

I want my VBA code to compare two rows of cells.

**Here's what my Sheet1 looks like:**

[image]

**And here's what my Sheet2 looks like:**

[image]

As you can see, I have the same number of cells to compare however, one of them is not the same.

What I want my VBA code to do, is to compare one by one the cells between Sheet1 and Sheet2. And once the code spots two cells who are not identical, a MsgBox appears saying "Cells are not the same". In that case, it is for cells "D1"

It sounds pretty basic and simple to do, but I'm really struggling.

Here are the first lines of code I have but it doesn't work:

```
Dim RangeSheet1 As Range, RangeSheet2 As Range

Set RangeSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Set RangeSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

Do While RangeSheet1.Value = RangeSheet2.Value

RangeSheet1.Offset(0,1)
RangeSheet2.Offset(0,1)
Loop

MsgBox "Cells are not the same"
```

Do you guys have any idea how I can do it the right way?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `RangeSheet1.Offset(0,1)` doesn't make sense, you need to reassign the variable so `set RangeSheet1=RangeSheet1.Offset(0,1)`. But you could do this easily with conditional formatting.

Comment: Also what happens when you reach the last column!?

Comment: Oh I'm stupid. Well when the last column is reached I just want the code to stop.

Comment: So is your code supposed to stop as soon as it reaches a difference?

Comment: Not really. What would be great is that, the code checks all the cells between the two sheets and at the end, once all cells have been checked, a MsgBox appears and says "Cells D1 are different".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a solution that compares all the cells in the sheets using a for loop. It exits the for loop when two cells are not equal, but if you need to compare more cells you can just remove that row. There are more efficient macros but this is a solution that I think should work for your needs.

```
Sub compareSheets()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, cell As Object

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")


For Each cell In sht1.Cells

    Dim currentCellAddress As String
    
    currentCellAddress = Replace(cell.Address, "$", "")
    
    If Not cell.Value = sht2.Range(currentCellAddress).value Then
        MsgBox "The cell " & currentCellAddress & " is not the same in both sheets."
        Exit For
    End If
    
Next cell

End Sub
```

EDIT:

I saw you to collect all the non-equal cells in a message box at the end. Then in that case, something like this should do the trick:

```
Sub compareSheets()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, cell As Object, refArray() As String, refCount As Integer

refCount = 0

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")


For Each cell In sht1.Cells

    Dim currentCellAddress As String
    
    currentCellAddress = Replace(cell.Address, "$", "")
    
    If Not cell.Value = sht2.Range(currentCellAddress).Value Then
        ReDim Preserve refArray(0 To refCount)
        refArray(refCount) = currentCellAddress
        refCount = refCount + 1
    End If
    
Next cell

Dim resultText As String, ref As Variant
 
For Each ref In refArray

    resultText = resultText & "  " & ref

Next ref

MsgBox "The following cells are not equal " & vbCrLf & resultText

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I wanted. Now I can use it to do more :)

Comment: I do not understand this line of your code: currentCellAddress = Replace(cell.Address, "$", "")
Can you explain it quickly?

Comment: @Haseo1997 - please accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Can I ask for your help one last time?
What I'd like to be able to do now, is that if the code encounters two different cells, it adds a to the right of the different cell in Sheet2. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: That line has two components. First of all, the cell.Address part collects the address from the current cell we stand at. However, it comes in the format of $A$1, so I directly put that into the function replace, which I use to replace the $ with “nothing” (“”). 

So all in all what that line does is to collect the address we are on in the format of A1. 

I will get back to you about the second question about adding an “a” to the right. It is possible by just writing sht2.range(currentCellAddress).value = “a” but then you need to check that sht2 cell is not a when checking equality also.

Comment: So basically in the condition of the if statement you would write:

If not (what it currently says) and not sht2.range(currentCellAddress).value=“a” then …

And underneath inside the if statement you would just write

sht2.range(currentCellAddress).offset(0,1).value= “a”.

The offset(0,1) means we are stepping one column to the right. :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations!
One last thing, what I'd like to be able to do now, is that if the code encounters two different cells, it adds a to the right of the different cell in Sheet2. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Any idea on how I could do that? I'm still stuck at it :/

Comment: @Haseo1997 I thought it was clear how to do it from my comment, but basically you just combine the code I wrote there with what is currently in the code. If it is not clear still maybe it is better if you contact me through dm since it is hard to write code here in the comment section.

Comment: How can I DM you? :/